# 'AClass' may not response to 'FunctionA' (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

Something about inheritance, I have two class here: female, the subclass of human, and human, it can run but showing issues.

Two issues here:

> main.m:29:10: 'human' may not respond to 'setSexy:'
>
> main.m:30:10: 'human' may not respond to 'isSexy'

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "female.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        human *sexyGirl = [[female alloc] init];

        [sexyGirl setName:@"SexyGirl"];
        [sexyGirl setGender:0];
        [sexyGirl setSexy:1];
        [sexyGirl isSexy];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

female.h

```
#import "human.h"

@interface female : human {
    BOOL sexy;
}

@property BOOL sexy;

-(void)isSexy;

@end
```

human.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface human : NSObject {
    NSInteger *hp;
    NSString *name;
    BOOL gender;
}

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger *hp;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL gender;

-(void) walk;

@end
```

Comment: Kindly don't post questions with this kind of meaning, someone may feel bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method name `isSexy` and `setSexy` in `human` class

You should change this  `human *sexyGirl = [[female alloc] init];`

to this  `female *sexyGirl = [[female alloc] init];`

Comment: Check once and if code works dont forget to accept and vote up :)

Answer (score 1):

when you do : `human *sexyGirl = [[female alloc] init];` 
you **upcast** the female to human. all the extra information (extra methods) a female has are still there but **no longer visible**

you can only work with what a human has from then on OR you **downcast** the variable again.
`[(female*)sexyGirl setSexy:1];`
`[(female*)sexyGirl isSexy]`

alternativly never downcast it and declare it as female * all the way

Comment: You have downcast and upcast backwards.  Downcast moves from a base class to a derived class; upcast is the opposite.  In this case, female to human is an upcast, and human to female is a downcast.

Comment: @JShapiro upsi :D thanks, ill change it ... damn ALWAYS get this wrong

Comment: No problem :)  The easiest way to remember is to think about how inheritance looks in a class diagram: http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/1106/updown.png

Comment: "upcast the female to human" - Let's just hope that no woman reads this (-: